# Wordpress URL Issues

Tags: wordpress, url

Hi I have a wordpress site and I'm having some url issues.
Why the url showing similar to this:

http://mysite.com/wp/index.php/testimonials/#.US3t4irt0mQ

Instead of only:
http://mysite.com/wp/index.php/testimonials/

Everytime I load a page, an added/extended URL characters ("#.US3t4irt0mQ") is seen on my address bar. What's causing this bug? Would be delighted to hear from you guys. Thanks

Comment: If it's added AFTER the page is loaded, it's something to do with javascript - possibly you've been hacked.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a permalinks issue. In settings > permalinks select the Common Setting "Post name" and click "Save Changes"

Comment: I tried it but still not fixed. Even on "Default" Permalink settings, those extended URL characters still appears on address bar.